# WinEdt cannot find MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, winedt

I installed MiKTeX. It works with TeXworks. Then I installed WinEdt and WinEdt did not recognize MikTeX. I did this many times before and WinEdt always recognized the location of MikTeX. The location of MiKTex is the same as on my other computer

C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64

What went wrong? I tried twice and WinEdt 9 simply does not find MiKTeX. Can I teach it where MiKTeX lives?

Comment: Perhaps you should update to WinEdt 10.3.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea. I got so used that WinEdt 9 and it worked well whenever I reinstalled it. But, it is time to move to WinEdt 10.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting. Sometimes one needs a push in the right direction